# Can I make my own OS using c programming language

Tags: systems-programming

With GUI or not ?
Will I make my own apps?
My own files Extension
can I boot my OS in an android device

> Sory for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest [osdev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Getting_Started)

To your question:
First c is a higher language, meaning it just deals more with "user interaction" such as the gui, network communication, etc but you have to build a base for higher languages like C.
To build this base you'll most likely have to learn assambly, which is a very difficult language for beginners. But if you are willing to spend much time in research, learning new programming languages and generally thinkering on complicated problems there's nothing hindering you.

Comment: Great advice thanks bro . I'll follow this siet seeking for help and books hoping i can develop my own OS

Answer (score 0):

What is your main reason for wanting to make an OS in C? You have to think about the purpose and what you actually want to do. In order to make an OS from scratch you need to be familiar with the basics of circuits and be very comfortable with binary.

To begin, I suggest you take a look at this GitHub repository and go from there:

[GitHub OS from scratch repo](https://github.com/tuhdo/os01)

I hope this was useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful advice i was new to programming that time (even til now i am new).

Comment: now i know a lot about assembly languages, computer architecture and logic gates .... i will try to learn more and then try again